# If a group $G$ contains an element a having exactly two conjugates, then $G$ has a proper normal subgroup $N \ne \{e\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If a group $G$ contains an element a having exactly two conjugates, then $G$ has a proper normal subgroup $N \ne \{e\}$

So my take on this is as follows: If we take $C_G(S)$ of S. This is a subgroup of G. If $C_G(S)=G$, then S has no conjugate but itself, so therefore $C_G(S)$ is a proper subgroup. If we suppose $C_G(S)=\{e\}$,then in order for there to be exactly two conjugates of S, then

For every $a \ne b \in G \ \{e\}, bxb^{-1} =axa^{-1}$ but $bxb^{-1}=axa^{-1} \to (a^{-1}b)xb^{-1}=xa^{-1} \to (a^{-1}b)x(a^{-1}b)^{-1}=x \to a^{-1}b \in C_G(S)$

Which means that $C_G(S)$ is actually nontrivial or that $a^{-1}b=e$ if and only if $a=b$, which would be a contradiction. Thus $C_G(S)$ is a nontrivial proper subgroup. Since there are exactly 2 conjugacy classes of S and they are in one to one correspondence with cosets of S, its centralizers' index $[G:C_G(S)]=s$. Subgroups of index $2$ are normal, so $C_G(S)$ is a proper nontrivial normal subgroup.

This approach seemed very different from other examples I have seen so I guess I am wondering if this approach makes sense.

Comment: The basic idea is correct: there is a subgroup of index $2$, and subgroups of index $2$ are always normal. However, I find your explanation a little confusing in places. The subgroup of index $2$ is the centralizer of an element $x$ such that $x$ has precisely two conjugates in $G$.

Comment: Instead of considering $C_G(S)$, streamline it by considering $C_G(x)$ where $x$ is the element of $G$ possessing exactly two conjugates.

Comment: Shouldn't the order of $G$ be $2<|G|<\infty$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be an element with exactly two conjugates, itself and some other element $b$.

Let $G$ act on the $X = \{a,b\}$ by conjugation. Consider the [class equation](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Class_equation_of_a_group_action) for this action: 
$$
|X| = |X_0| + \sum |G/G_x| = 2.
$$

We notice that $|X_0| = 1$ (since the identity actions lies in $X_0$, and $a$ isn't fixed by the action of $b$). Hence there is a unique element $x\in X$ such that $[G:G_x] = 2$, and then $G_x$ must be normal since [every subgroup of index 2](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Index_2_is_Normal) is normal.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g$ be an element with two conjugates then $\mid N(g)\mid\,=\frac{\mid\mathbb{G}\mid}{2}$ where $N(g)$ is normaliser subgroup with respect to $g$ and any subgroup with index 2 is normal hence $N(g)$ is a non-trivial normal group.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another argument.

Let $\{a,b\}$ be a conjugacy class. Notice that if $aba^{-1}=a$, then $a=b$. Contradiction. So it has to be that $aba^{-1}=b$, which means that $a$ and $b$ commute.

Since $\{a,b\}$ is a conjugacy class, for any $g\in G$, $ga=ag$ or $ga=bg$. Also, $gb=ag$ or $gb=bg$.

Now, consider the subgroup $N$ generated by $a$ and $b$. $N$ is of the form $\{a^{h_1}b^{k_1}...a^{h_n}b^{k_n}|h_i, k_i\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. 
Since we can replace "$g$ times $a$ or $b$" by "$a$ or $b$ times $g$," $ga^{h_1}b^{k_1}...a^{h_n}b^{k_n}g^{-1}=a^{h_1'}b^{k_1'}...a^{h_m'}b^{k_m'}gg^{-1}=a^{h_1'}b^{k_1'}...a^{h_m'}b^{k_m'}$ is again in $N$. So $N$ is normal.

If $N=G$, then everything in $G$ is a product of powers of $a$ and $b$. This gives us that everything commutes with one another. So any conjugacy class can only have one element. Contradiction.

So $N$ is a proper normal subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

We will make use of following two lemma in the proof:

**Lemma(1):** If a group $G$ acts on a set $S$, then the cardinal number of the orbit of $x\in S$ is the index $[G : G_x]$, where $G_x=\{g\in G\mid gx=x\}\leq G$ is stabilizer of $x$.

**Lemma(2):** If $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $[G:H]=2$, then $H$ is normal in $G$.

---

**Proof:** Element $a$ having exactly two conjugate means cardinality of conjugacy class of $a$ is $2$, that is $|\bar{a}|=|\{gag^{-1}\mid g\in G\}|=2$. By lemma(1), $|\bar{a}|=[G:G_a]=2$. By lemma(2), $G_a$ is normal in $G$. We claim $G_a\neq \langle e\rangle$. Assume towards contradiction $G_a=\langle e\rangle$. Then $[G:G_a]=[G:\langle e\rangle]=|G|=2$. Note $e\notin \{gag^{-1}\mid g\in G\}=\{a,hah^{-1}\}$, otherwise $gag^{-1}=e$ for some $g\in G$ implies $a=e$ and $|\bar{a}|=|\bar{e}|=1$. So $\{a,hah^{-1},e\}\subseteq G$ and $3\leq |G|$. Thus we reach contradiction. Hence $\exists G_a (\neq \{ e\})$ normal subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score -1):

Simplifying $a,b$ argument a little:

Let $g$ be the element with exactly two conjugates. Suppose $C_G(g) = \{e\}$. Since $g \in C_G(g)$, this means $g = e$.

By Lagrange's Theorem, $[G : C_G(g)] = 2$ imples $\lvert G \rvert = 2$, so $G = \{e, h\}$. The two conjugates of $g$ are itself and $hgh^{-1}$, but both are $e$, contradicting $g$ having two conjugates.

Conclude $C_G(g) \ne \{e\}$.